# How many connections are created and reused by Golang

Tags: go, connection-pooling

Anybody knows how can I test the numbers of connections that transport is currently creating on the pool of the connections, it is clear that in the code I have put MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 5 like number maximum of connections on the pool and DisableKeepAlives: false like the option which let to reuse the connection
 but I do not sure about how Go is managed this topic and the documentation is not clear [Source-code-transport.go](http://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go) , [Documentation-net/http](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

[Server](http://play.golang.org/p/bvdiS0HFJS) is a example of a server that receive a XML and send the same XML like response with an attribute more.

[Client](http://play.golang.org/p/B0o6teNktF) is the code that has the configuration of the pool and send 100 request to server.

Comment: You can look at how the `DefaultTransport` is constructed, near the documentation of RoundTripper: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper.  Note how the `Dial` function is the component that does the connection creation.  A `Dial` function itself returns a `Conn` (http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial).  Judicious use of delegation should let you keep track whenever a `Dial` is happening and when a corresponding `Conn.Close()` is performed.

Comment: Just speaking generally, you could also look at what syscalls your program is making or what it has open with general OS tools (`strace`, `netstat -ap`, etc.)--[Julia Evans wrote about this a while back](http://jvns.ca/blog/2014/04/20/debug-your-programs-like-theyre-closed-source/).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".